# ensure web api controller returns valid HTML

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax

I think my web api 2 controller is returning JSON or some type of XML. I've debugged my game and stepped through the program and everything looks ok in Visual Studio.

However, when my ajax method gets the data via the controller, there is a slash before every quote in addition to an extra set of quotations like this:

```
 <img id="\"12345\"" title="\"monster1\""
 src="\"https://xxx.cloudfront.net/bucket/monster1.jpg\"" width="\"200\""
 height="\"200\"" />
```

Yet when I step through the program, I can see that my method, "monsterFactory.returnMonsterImageTag" is returning a valid image tag:

```
<img id="12345" title="monster1" src="https://xxx.cloudfront.net/bucket/monster1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

So this must be happening in my controller, which is this:

```
    Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As String) As String
        Dim monsterFactory As New MonsterFactory
        Return monsterFactory.returnMonsterImageTag(id)
    End Function
```

Which is used by my ajax function in my page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/monsterPhoto/' + monsterID,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#monster").html(data);
        },
        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

So my question is, how can I prevent my controller from escaping the quotes like that and return valid html?

Thanks!

Comment: The double quotes in the string are being escaped, although it shouldn't cause an issue: https://jsfiddle.net/bp6gL9xx/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm, sorry, it's adding an extra quotation in addition to the slash.  I've updated my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you having issues because while seeing this behavior?

Comment: URL encode your html with `HttpUtility.URLEncode` method. Decode it with `decodeURIComponent` method in Javascript when you get it in your callback. HTML can't be sent through without encoding.

Comment: @trevster344 thanks, that worked.